# awk: how to extract from file A the columns with indexes specified in file B?

Tags: bash, unix, awk

My **file A** has the format below, with hundreds of thousands of columns and thousands of rows:

```
1000->100001    DOSE    2.000   2.000   2.000   2.000   2.000 ....
1001->100101    DOSE    1.988   1.988   2.000   2.000   2.000 ....
1001->100101    DOSE    1.933   2.000   2.000   2.000   2.000 ....
1002->100201    DOSE    2.000   2.000   2.000   2.000   2.000 ....
1002->100201    DOSE    2.000   2.000   2.000   2.000   2.000 ....
```

While my **file B** (thousands of entries) has the following format:

```
SNP,Al1,Al2,Freq1,MAF,AvgCall,Rsq,Genotyped,key,pos,gene_key
20:29649365,C,T,0.93021,0.06979,0.93021,0.10115,,803428,29649365,12
20:29649737,A,G,0.93914,0.06086,0.93914,0.14303,,803442,29649737,12
20:29649765,T,G,0.99963,0.00037,0.99963,0.13918,,803443,29649765,12
20:29650462,A,T,0.89387,0.10613,0.89388,0.12864,,803456,29650462,12
```

What I want to do is extract from file A the first two columns plus the columns specified in the "key" column from file B. I spent some time trying to figure out how to do this using awk, but it's been taking way too long for something that theoretically should not be too difficult.

My specific question is: once I extract the "key" entries from file B, how do I pipe these values into the awk command for file A?

Manual command for the first 3 columns in file B:

```
awk '{print $1, $2, $803428, $803442, $803442}' fileA > output.txt
```

**EDITS:**

There is no common column between **file A** and **file B**. The values in column 803428 in **file A** would represent results for the SNP "20:29649365" from **file B**.

If the command to be run were:

```
awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}' fileA
```

The result would be:

```
1000->100001 DOSE 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000
1001->100101 DOSE 1.988 1.988 2.000 2.000 2.000
1002->100201 DOSE 1.933 1.999 2.000 2.000 2.000
1003->100301 DOSE 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000
1004->100401 DOSE 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000
```

**Specific examples I am using to test the awk commands given as solutions.**

fileA:

```
1000->100001    DOSE    2.000   2.000   2.000   2.000   2.000
1001->100101    DOSE    1.988   1.988   2.000   2.000   2.000
1001->100101    DOSE    1.933   2.000   1.500   2.000   2.000
1002->100201    DOSE    2.000   2.000   2.000   2.000   1.622
1002->100201    DOSE    2.000   2.000   2.000   2.000   2.000
```

fileB:

```
SNP,Al1,Al2,Freq1,MAF,AvgCall,Rsq,Genotyped,key,pos,gene_key
20:29649365,C,T,0.93021,0.06979,0.93021,0.10115,,3,29649365,12
20:29649737,A,G,0.93914,0.06086,0.93914,0.14303,,4,29649737,12
20:29650462,A,T,0.89387,0.10613,0.89388,0.12864,,6,29650462,12
```

Desired output (columns 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 - last 3 from the key column of fileB):

```
1000->100001    DOSE    2.000   2.000   2.000
1001->100101    DOSE    1.988   1.988   2.000
1001->100101    DOSE    1.933   2.000   2.000
1002->100201    DOSE    2.000   2.000   2.000
1002->100201    DOSE    2.000   2.000   2.000
```

Comment: why is it `$803428, $803442, $803442` why `803456` was ignored? and, `pos` column in fileB is actually `29649365,29649737....`, what you meant was `key` column?

Comment: please show us your required output per the sample inputs for `fileA` and `fileB`. Good luck.

Comment: @Kent - you are right about the pos/key mistake - I'm changing this. 803456 was ignored just for the purpose of the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here's an updated version which should reproduce your output.

```
awk 'ARGIND==2&&!/SNP/{cols[++i]=$9}ARGIND==4{printf("%s %s",$1,$2);
      for(j=1;j<=i;j++)printf(" %s%s",$cols[j],j<i?"":"\n");}' FS=',' B.txt FS='[ \t]+' A.txt
```

It's complicated a bit by the different field separators in the two files and the header in the B-file that must be ignored. But the key here is that `$` accepts a variable, not just a constant integer. This approach stores the list of columns in the `cols` array, and iterates through them for each row in A.

Switching field separators between files is done via dummy files `FS=','` and 'FS='[ \t]+'`, which means that our actual files have arginds of 2 and 4.

Comment: Hi amaurea, the command does not work as expected - I put the output from your awk command at the end of my question.

Comment: @Alexandra : please edit your question to include you desired output, given the 2 sample files you have included. Otherwise you're asking people to spend time guessing about what you need. Also, this sort of question (with different terminology) appears 2-3 x a week. Are you taking a class and is this an assignment? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter - it's work related. If you can find a specific question that addresses the problem described, please feel free to reference it.

Comment: @Alexandra: I've updated my answer with a new version that reproduces your output. I had previously misunderstood what you wanted to do, and thought there would be one line in B for each line in A, and that only one column was to be extracted from each row. The new version collects column numbers from B and then extracts all those columns from every line of A.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to read the column index from fileB (the `key` column, not the `pos`) and print those columns from fileA, also keep the order of the col index in fileB, you can try:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{c[NR]=$(NF-2);n=NR;next}
{printf "%s %s",$1,$2;
for(i=2;i<=n;i++)printf " %s",$c[i];print ""}' FS=',' fileB FS=' ' fileA
```

Comment: Hi Kent, the command does not work as expected - I put the output from your awk command at the end of my question.

Comment: @Alexandra  does it help if you change the 3rd line into `for(i=1;i<=n;i++)printf "%s ",$c[i]; print ""}' FS=...` ?

Comment: I am getting the same output as before with this modification.

Comment: @Alexandra I see, in your fileB, there is a header line, this line should be ignored. try the updated answer, it should work for you.

Comment: the output is the same as fileA, columns 5 and 7 are not removed.

Comment: @Alexandra sry, my bad again.... it should be `awk ' ...' FS=',' fileB  FS=' ' fileA` ... I should do a test next time. `FS=' '` before `fileA` was missing. also it should be `$(NF-2)` , answer updated.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help - the command works now. I upvoted your answer, but accepted amaurea's answer, since he got back to me first.

Comment: @Alexandra no problem, important is your problem gets solved. it would be better if you could understand the solution and write some test codes, so that you can cook by yourself next time you are hungry.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach: apply an awk script on fileB that *generates* another awk script, to be applied on fileA.

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F, 'NR>1{a=a",$"$9}END{print"{print $1,$2"a"}"}' < fileB > cols.awk
awk -f cols.awk fileA
```

Or as a one-liner, without intermediate file:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk "$(awk -F, 'NR>1{a=a",$"$9}END{print"{print $1,$2"a"}"}' < fileB)" fileA
```